# How can I join tables and preserve my ON conditionals if they're missing from one side?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Let's say I have two tables:

```
dbo.CurrentWeekData
MetricID | Country | CurrentValue
---------------------------------
    1    | France  |   10
    2    | France  |   20
    3    | France  |   30
    1    | Germany |   11
    2    | Germany |   12

dbo.PreviousWeekData
MetricID | Country | PreviousValue
---------------------------------
    1    | France  |   100
    2    | France  |   200
    1    | Germany |   500
    2    | Germany |   501
    3    | Germany |   502
```

I'd like to join these tables to obtain the following result:

```
MetricID | Country | CurrentValue | PreviousValue
--------------------------------------------------
    1    | France  |     10       |     100
    2    | France  |     20       |     200
    3    | France  |     30       |     NULL
    1    | Germany |     11       |     500
    2    | Germany |     12       |     501
    3    | Germany |     NULL     |     502
```

I've tried all sorts of joins but, even with a FULL OUTER JOIN, the last row is completely NULL except for the PreviousValue cell. Note that I want to preserve the MetricID and Country in all rows and just have CurrentValue or PreviousValue be NULL when data is missing.

Is there a JOIN, or some other SQL mechanism, that will combine these tables and provide NULL cells if data is present in one table but not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `full outer join` should work:

```
select coalesce(w.metricid, p.metricid) as metricid,
       coalesce(w.country, p.country) as country,
       c.currentvalue, w.previousvalue
from currentweekdata w full outer join
     previousweekdata p
     on w.metricid = p.metricid and w.country = p.country;
```

You probably just need the `coalesce()` for the keys used for the `join`.